# How to integrate Vaadin [version 23.2.8] and Grails [version 5.2.5]

Tags: grails, vaadin, integration

I was just wondering if it were possible to integrate Vaadin [version 23.2.8] and Grails [version 5.2.5] since earlier version (7 and 8) are quite old.
Just requesting a piece of advice.
Thanks

Comment: Vaadin needs a "servlet environment" and plays nicely with Spring - so if still works with Grails of today, you should just have to follow the tutorials of how to use Vaadin with Gradle and Spring and add the deps. What have you tried?  How did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if there is a lot of benefit in doing so. Grails and Vaadin are not entirely mutually exclusive, but there's a lot of duplicated functionality between the two. If you use Vaadin for the UI, you won't need GSP, the AJAX stuff, or tag libraries. Out of the top-level functionality to use with Vaadin, the only useful thing from Grails that I can think of is GORM. The Groovy language should be usable, but that's not unique to Grails.